# What changes do I need for this Codeforces challenge 784F?

Tags: c++, sorting

Link to the problem in question: http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/784/F

It's nothing but a sorting problem so I used bubble sort on my array. But when I submit my answer it keeps rejecting on test 1 even though it works just fine when I run it. I made sure I chose the right compiler for my code so that's not the problem. Is there something wrong with my code?

Here's my code:

```
int arr[10];

/* number of inputs */
int n;
cin >> n;

/* inputting n numbers to the array */
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    cin >> arr[i];

/* bubble sort array */
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; ++j) {
        if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
            int temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
            arr[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}

/* printing all the numbers in array */
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cout << arr[i] << ' ';
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: What happens if `n` is set to value larger than 10? Hint: your array is defined as `int arr[10]`

Comment: Other than that, why bubble sort if there is a time limit etc. on the code? And what does `I made sure I chose the right compiler` mean?

Comment: Looking at the site, it seems that not only do you have to sort the numbers but you also have to remove any duplicates: 
Input: 3 3 1 2
Output: 1 2 3

Comment: (Something is seriously wrong with this task. Sorting 10 byte with up to 64MB memory used? Sorting in "non-descending order" (random order)? And the thing about duplicates could be both intentional or a typo, it's not mentioned anywhere)

Comment: Thanks for commenting guys but I just found out that this problem was a part of "April Fool's Day Contest" and there was more to it than I initially thought. Problem solved! I should have looked more into this before posing a question oh well..

Comment: There is nothing wrong with trying to implement everything yourself, but the question doesn't state that you can't use std::vector, std::sort, std::unique or std::swap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to implement everything your self, just use the standard library:

```
// number of inputs
int n;
std::cin >> n;

// Vector storing the numbers
std::vector<int> v(n);

// Input n numbers
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    std::cin >> arr[i];
}

// Sort the numbers
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

// Removed all duplicates (all numbers are unique)
auto last = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end());
v.erase(last, v.end()); 

// Print all the numbers
for (int i : v)
  std::cout << i << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```